# In Hyperledger Fabric, how to keep chaincode(source code) private at the time of deployment?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

When I deploy a chaincode on Hyperledger Fabric Platform, the compilation process is carried out by the Fabric core system, via a shell script. The input to that shell script is the source code.

1. Is there a provision in Hyperledger fabric to deploy a binary v chaincode (i.e. already compiled one like a .exe)?
2. Is the chaincode source code logged anywhere?

Searched official documentation but no luck so far.

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode install -n mychaincode-v 1.0 -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1: No,officially there is no way to do that.

For Q. 2: Chaincode has to be installed in at least one peer, and then has to be instantiated with a transaction that has to be approved according to the policy, so the answer depends on what you mean by anywhere.

Comment: Chaincode source only stays within the local boundary of the peer(s) on which you install it.

Comment: @GariSingh We are using a third party Fabric Platform. In the chaincode there is logic which is our Organization's IP, and we want to protect it. This need makes the question relevant. I was wondering if there are any provisions in the core system that can help us achieve such privacy levels.